# Setting Property via a String

Tags: python, properties, setattr

I'm trying to set a Python class property outside of the class via the ***setattr(self, item, value)*** function.

```
class MyClass:
    def getMyProperty(self):
        return self.__my_property

    def setMyProperty(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        self.__my_property = value

    my_property = property( getMyProperty, setMyProperty )
```

And in another script, I create an instance and want to specify the property and let the property mutator handle the simple validation.

```
myClass = MyClass()
new_value = None

# notice the property in quotes
setattr(myClass, 'my_property', new_value)
```

The problem is that it doesn't appear to be calling the *setMyProperty(self, value)* mutator. For a quick test to verify that it doesn't get called, I change the mutator to:

```
    def setMyProperty(self, value):
        raise ValueError('WTF! Why are you not being called?')
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        self.__my_property = value
```

I'm fairly new to Python, and perhaps there's another way to do what I'm trying to do, but can someone explain why the mutator isn't being called when *setattr(self, item, value)* is called?

Is there another way to set a property via a string? I need the validation inside the mutator to be executed when setting the property value.

Comment: Do you actually define a property using your setter and getter functions?  Your code does not show such a definition.  How is Python supposed to know what getter and setter to use for `my_property`?

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Oops, forgot to add that in the example. But, Yes, I'm defining that in the actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   def get(self): return 10
...   def setprop(self, val): raise ValueError("hax%s"%str(val))
...   prop = property(get, setprop)
...
>>> i = MyClass()
>>> i.prop =4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in setprop
ValueError: hax4
>>> i.prop
10
>>> setattr(i, 'prop', 12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in setprop
ValueError: hax12
```

The code you pasted seems to do the same as mine, except that my class inherits from `object`, but that's cause I'm running Python 2.6 and I thought that in 2.7 all classes automatically inherit from `object`. Try that, though, and see if it helps.

To make it even clearer: try just doing `myClass.my_property = 4`. Does that raise an exception? If not then it's an issue with inheriting from `object` - properties only work for new-style classes, i.e. classes that inherit from `object`.

Comment: Actually, the last paragraph is the solution: Python 2.7 still distinguishes between old-style and new-style classes.

Comment: The issue was not specifying that it inherits from **object**. Thank you.